# Unable to import png or jpg images in Android Studio

Tags: android, image, android-studio, import, png

Since the new versions of Android Studio (Starting at 4.2 I think), I haven't been able to import images correctly. Let me explain what I mean by 'correctly'.

Before, importing an image of a high resolution (usually xxxhdpi) would automatically be converted to different sizes for lower resolutions (down to ldpi). Nowadays, all Android Studio seems to want to do is convert images to some grey rectangle and say "here you go, use that".

Now I don't think this is the desired behaviour which makes me believe that there is possibly some configuration to change or update that I have missed.

Below is the image I would like to import (with its resolution) and what Android Studio shows me:

Original: 832x456 image in PNG format
[image: Original image]

Android Studio import:
[image]

Can someone either explain if I'm doing something wrong or if this is the actual behaviour now ?

If this is the behaviour, my only option is to write a simple python script to generate the correct resolution versions based on the Android guidelines but I'd like to avoid this if at all possible.

Comment: Is this WYSIWYG? I mean, what is the result?

Comment: Yep, original image is in colour and the resulting import is what is in the screenshot, a grey version of the image

Comment: I have the same issue, can you tell me how to solve it? if u have found a solution...

Comment: I used this website: https://hotpot.ai/icon-resizer

I'm still looking for a way to use the native import in Android Studio...